# Running GUI within docker despite error

Tags: gui, docker

I am running ROS within docker and I try to use a GUI ROS node.(turtlesime)

I succeeded (I could see the turtle) but in the terminal where I run it I got the errors:

```
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
Couldn't get V3D IDENT0: No such device
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to create dri screen
libEGL warning: DRI2: could not open /dev/dri/card1 (no such file or directory)
```

I don't understand what each of these errors or warning mean. Can someone help me here?

Comment: What is ROS? What turtle?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System

Comment: *"I succeeded (I could see the turtle) but in the terminal where I run it I got the errors"* -> So is there actually a problem besides this?  Many GUI apps are constantly spitting out errors if you know where to look for them.  The X server will also do this and when initializing it commonly tries options such as drivers in some priority order, if it cannot use the first one it asks for it tries another, etc. -- although in this case it isn't initializing (because docker uses the host display), there is still a parallel.  This is I guess openEGL/Mesa errors.

Comment: Couple that with the fact console output may be *incomplete* (in that it may show errors but not the more trivial messages that follow implying the error isn't fatal), and what you have is something worth consulting *when and if something goes wrong* and need not be paid too much attention otherwise.